# "mod" not working in <ace:datatable>

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable, icefaces

I am using .Nowm when i apply a condition with `eq` then it is working great in datatable.
For Reference:

```
<ace:dataTable id="tbl" ..... rowIndexVar="row" 
rowStyleClass="#{((row+2)/2 eq 1)?'chkred':'chknone'}">
```

but When i am using `mod` like this

```
<ace:dataTable id="tbl" ..... rowIndexVar="row" 
rowStyleClass="#{((row+2)/2 mod 0.0)?'chkred':'chknone'}">
```

it throws an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert ? of type class java.lang.Double to class java.lang.Boolean
```

I want to know that Why this code is throwing this exception and how can I use "mod" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its cause the result of `mod` is a double and not boolean , and you were trying to treat that double result as a boolean

for example `#{10 mod 4}` will result in *2* and not *true* or *false*

Also, You can't use `+` in EL Expression

try something like this

```
<ace:dataTable id="tbl" ..... rowIndexVar="row" 
    rowStyleClass="#{(row mod 2 eq 0)?'chkred':'chknone'}">
```

Comment: awesome stuff man :) it is working but I want to tell you that it didn't worked as i want.Actually i want that by applying this condition #{((row+2)/2 mod 0.0 eq 0)?'chkred':'chknone'}" it apply chkred class on odd rows and chknone class on even rows but it always applying chkred class :( .. it seems it always return "true" for this condition.Any idea about this?

Comment: for start try writing out the value like this `#{(row+2)/2 mod 0.0`} to see whats going on and what actual value is being returned at every row... continue from there... b.t.w , shouldn't you do something like this `rowStyleClass="#{(row mod 2 eq 0)?'chkred':'chknone'}"`

Comment: Em amazed.. it is just printing "NaN"... What does that mean?

Comment: owo... just noticed that `+` sign you can't use it like this in EL expression  , does`rowStyleClass="#{(row mod 2 eq 0)?'chkred':'chknone'}"` works for you?